# How to get all latest commits messages for Xcode Bot “Run Script” Trigger?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode6

I'm using Xcode server bots to look at one of my branches every 5 minutes and in case of new commits - archive them and upload to Crashlytics Beta. Currently, I'm using a release notes text file that I need to manually update.
What I want is for the bot to send all the latest commit messages as release notes.
How can I do that?

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found a solution, yet?